# pandas fillna getting type error

Tags: python, pandas

```
merge_all['points'].fillna(merge_all['points'].median()[0], inplace=True)
```

I want to fill Nan values  with median  but getting `type erros` saying

> 'float' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2):

`merge_all['points'].median()` is a float itself. No need to subscript it with 0.